# php __construct() - please explain what the argument means

Tags: php, function, oop, constructor, arguments

I searched for an answer but I couldn't find. I know the concept of classes, objects, constructors etc.

What I don't understand is, this kind of syntax in PHP.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig) {
    $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
}
```

Specifically I don't understand the argument of constructor. Where it comes from? From another class? Which file should I look for $resourceConfig?

Could someone please explain? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It comes from you when you instantiate the class i.e. `$x = new ClassName($TheParameterGoesHere);`

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers. Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config` is an object of class `Config` under namespace `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\`.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config $resourceConfig) {
    $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's an instance of a class. Namely: class `Config` in the namespace `Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel`

Answer (score 0):

visit here, you may find something use ful
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/

Comment: a link **[link only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)** is likely to be removed. Try to provide a bit of substance, and why in your opinion the best way is `using API`.

Answer (score 0):

That type of constructor has 2 purposes:

- dependency injection: basically your class is dependant on that config object to work
- type hint: you make sure you operate with that precise type of config object to avoid mistakes (from you or other developers)

To oversimplify things the idea is like this:

```
$config = new \Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config();
$obj = new YourClass($config);
```